# IndexOutOfBoundsException in my implementation of Live wallpaper

Tags: java, android, rendering, live-wallpaper, indexoutofboundsexception

Method changeFlowers is failing with Index Out of Bound Exception.

I am new to java, I am calling method "changeColor()" of already instanciated FishOne (Arraylist rederable class)
But it is failing with Index Out of Bound Exception.

```
public void changeFlowers(int i)
{


        FlowerOne f1 = (FlowerOne)(this._fishes.get(i));   // Is this the right way to call ????
        f1.changeColor(this._theme);


}
```

Code below Aquarium.java, FishOne.java
Thanks for your help in advance.

---

### Aquarium.java,

```
public class Aquarium {
private AquariumThread _aquariumThread; 
private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;   
private ArrayList<Renderable> _fishes;  
private Bitmap _backgroundImage;
private Context _context;


public void render(){
    Canvas canvas = null;
    try{

        canvas = this._surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized (this._surfaceHolder) {
            this.onDraw(canvas);
        }

    }finally{
        if(canvas != null){
            this._surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }   
}


protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.renderBackGround(canvas);
    for (Renderable renderable : this._fishes) {
        renderable.render(canvas);
    }
};

public void initialize(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    this._fishes = new ArrayList<Renderable>();
}



protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.renderBackGround(canvas);
    for (Renderable renderable : this._fishes) {
        renderable.render(canvas);
    }
};


public void start(){
    this._aquariumThread.switchOn();
}


public void stop(){
    boolean retry = true;
    this._aquariumThread.switchOff();
    while (retry) {
        try {
         this._aquariumThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // we will try it again and again...
        }
    }
}


public synchronized void addFishes() {      

Point startPoint1 = new Point(1,300);
this._fishes.add(new fishOne(this._context, this, startPoint1, 90));

Point startPoint2 = new Point(100,300);
this._fishes.add(new fishOne(this._context, this, startPoint2, 90));

Point startPoint3 = new Point(200,300);
this._fishes.add(new fishOne(this._context, this, startPoint3, 90));

}





public void changeFlowers(int i)
{


        FlowerOne f1 = (FlowerOne)(this._fishes.get(i));
        f1.changeColor(this._theme);


}


}
```

---

### FishOne.java

```
public class fishOne extends Animal {
private static final int TOTAL_FRAMES_IN_SPRITE = 1;
private static final int CLOWN_FISH_FPS = 1; 

int _fishColor;
Bitmap leftBitmap;
Bitmap rightBitmap;


public fishOne(Context context, Aquarium aquarium,  Point startPoint, int speed){       

    super(context, aquarium);   
    this.changeColor(1);
    this.initialize(this.leftBitmap, this.rightBitmap, CLOWN_FISH_FPS, TOTAL_FRAMES_IN_SPRITE, startPoint, speed);

}


public void changeColor(int mfishColor)
{


    switch(mfishColor) {
    case 1:

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    this.leftBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), com.gotit.livewallpaper.fishshd.R.drawable.fish1, options);

    BitmapFactory.Options options1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options1.inPurgeable = true;
    this.rightBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), com.gotit.livewallpaper.fishshd.R.drawable.fish2, options1);

        break;

    case 2:
    BitmapFactory.Options options2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options2.inPurgeable = true;
    this.leftBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), com.gotit.livewallpaper.fishshd.R.drawable.redfish1, options2);

    BitmapFactory.Options options3 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options3.inPurgeable = true;
    this.rightBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), com.gotit.livewallpaper.fishshd.R.drawable.redfish2, options3);

        break;
    default:
    }


}


public void render(Canvas canvas){
    super.render(canvas);   
}

}
```

Comment: How are you calling the method?

Comment: the index bigger than the _fishes arraylist' size, please check the i and _fishes.size()

Comment: Hi npinti, this is how i am calling the method f1.changeColor(this._theme);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the complete logic how the code is error safe. Basically If you are sure that changeFlowers will not called with argument i greater than the ArrayList size then it's Ok otehrwise you have to put the vheck in changeFlowers function.

like

```
public void changeFlowers(int i)
{

    if(null!=this._fishes && this._fishes.size()>i){

        FlowerOne f1 = (FlowerOne)(this._fishes.get(i));
        f1.changeColor(this._theme);
}


}
```

But would be better to make code safe from where this function get called as the actulal problem is there. **Above code will stop the error but you also need to make it correct where the fumction get called.**